# Get object initialization syntax from C# list

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection

I have a List of type employee.

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
    }

List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
```

Assume if this list has 10 items, from this list, I want to generate object initialization code. So basically I should get a string like this:

```
    "Employee e = new Employee{Name: "A", Id:1, Level:1};
    Employee e = new Employee{Name: "B", Id:2, Level:2};
    Employee e = new Employee{Name: "C", Id:3, Level:1};
Employee e = new Employee{Name: "D", Id:4, Level:6};
    Employee e = new Employee{Name: "E", Id:5, Level:2};
    Employee e = new Employee{Name: "F", Id:6, Level:5}
Employee e = new Employee{Name: "G", Id:7, Level:4};
    Employee e = new Employee{Name: "H", Id:8, Level:3};
    Employee e = new Employee{Name: "I", Id:9, Level:1};
Employee e = new Employee{Name: "J", Id:10, Level:1}";
```

The reason I am doing this is, I am getting list of records from database but it does not have a sort order (another property). I need to manually add the sort order to each item (hard code). 
So if I don't automate this, the only other option I will have would require me to create the object manually(instead of getting the values from database) and add SortOrder property to each object.

Comment: Do you actually _need_ to generate initialization code or do you just need the objects that the code would produce?

Comment: @DStanley: i just need the objects that will form the list. once i have all the object definition, I will add another property to it and then create another list.

Comment: Then don't try to generate initialization code that you will need to compile at run-time. Create the objects in a `foreach` or `for` loop.  If you show how you would do it in a loop then we can help convert it to a Linq projection.

Comment: @DStanley: I think, i did not explain it well. like i mentioned in the question, I need syntax or text for each object in the list that will actually help build me another similar list.

Comment: Any my point is don't try to generate code that needs to be compiled at run-time.  Show how you would create the new employee or set the sort order property on existing employees.

Comment: @DStanley: Assuming, I get a text like this `"Employee e = new Employee{Name: "A", Id:1, Level:1};
    Employee e = new Employee{Name: "B", Id:2, Level:2};`, I will manually add the new property. By that I mean, I will copy it to another text editor and add the new property. I am not looking to do that part through program.

Comment: I think the question is why NOT do that part in the program?  Rather than making one program that queries a database and creates source code for a second program, have just one program.  Query an object from the database and project the results into an object that has all the database fields plus your sort order field too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how having this code will help you, but here it is:

```
String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    empList.Select(x =>
        $"Employee e = new Employee() {{ Name = \"{x.Name}\", Id = {x.Id}, Level = \"{x.Level}\" }};"));
```

I'm going to suggest that a better option would be for you to create a sorting dictionary, to create the manual sort order, and then use this to sort your list that you load from the database.

Do something like this:

```
var sorter = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 1, "c" },
    { 2, "a" },
    { 3, "b" },
    { 4, "c" },
    { 5, "c" },
    { 6, "a" },
    { 7, "a" },
    { 8, "b" },
    { 9, "d" },
    { 10, "c" },
};

empList =
    empList
        .OrderBy(e => sorter.ContainsKey(e.Id) ? sorter[e.Id] : "z")
        .ToList();
```